# proper way to read & update local storage variables

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Using Android Studio 3.4.1, with Kotlin language.

If I'm storing ~50 data values in local storage, for example:

- Name: Kyle
- Drink: Monster
- Age: 22
- etc...

What is the easiest method of updating a single data point...?

Right now I'm envisioning:

1. Use InputStreamReader combined with BufferedReader.readLine for reading each line.
2. Store all of the data in a local variable.
3. Use some lame method of .Replace to update one part of the string.
4. Write all the data in order, back to the file.

But this seems a bit cumbersome, and extremely primitive... I can only assume there are easier, more standardized ways of doing this.

Comment: Have your values in an object. Then, choose a persistence mechanism to save that object to/from some piece of content. That could be JSON, XML, Kotlin serialization, Java serialization, Room/SQLite, etc.

Comment: have a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room